# Validate a date range in XSD for either date or dateTime?

Tags: date, datetime, xsd, date-range

I have an element that accepts either a date value or a dateTime value. Right now the xsd for the element looks like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="sTidpunkt">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:date xs:dateTime"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

How can I expand this to validate that the date part of the date or dateTime value is within a certain range? For example it has to be later than 1980-06-01 and earlier than 1990-06-01.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reference information for XSD simple types is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime

Based on that specification, I recommend the following:

1. Declare two new global simple type definitions: (e.g. `myDate` and `myDateTime`)
2. Add facets to those simple type definitions to limit the values in whatever way you require.
3. Change your memberTypes attribute to refer to the new simple types.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a good solution. I will look into that.